# Forwarding historic (old) syslog to syslog server

Tags: linux, logs, syslog, rsyslog, rsyslogd

We can forward syslogs to syslog server by making the below entry in syslog.conf/rsyslog.conf

```
*.*<space/tab>@<syslog_server_name>:<port_no>
```

However, this only sends new syslogs, which are generated after making this entry. But I want to send old syslogs also that are generated before making this entry. Is there any way to send old/historic syslogs to syslog server?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure rsyslog to read from existing files, for example:

```
module(load="imfile" PollingInterval="10")

input(type="imfile"
      File="/var/log/apache2/*access.log"
      Tag="apache2-access"
      Severity="info"
      Facility="local6")
```

docs: https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/modules/imfile.html